# Using CMakeLists to include headers from other library

Tags: c++, cmake

I am struggling with getting one of my libraries to include header files from another of my libraries.

My structure is as follows:

[image]

I want to reference amber.common in amber.engine, both as a library and to have access to the header files.

The CMakeLists.txt from amber.common looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(amber.common VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_library(amber.common 
  core/amber_object.cpp
  concurrency/thread_lock.cpp
  debugging/stopwatch.cpp
  environment/environment.cpp
  events/event_handler.cpp
  logging/amber_logging.cpp
  memory/amber_memory.cpp
  parsers/parser.cpp
  parsers/xml_parser.cpp
  strings/string_converter.cpp
  strings/string_helper.cpp)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

While the CMakeLists.txt from amber.engine looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(amber.engine VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_library(amber.engine 
  core/amber_configuration.cpp
  core/window.cpp)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

In amber.engine I have a file called *window.h* that includes a file from amber.common called *amber_object.h*, but there is an error telling me it cannot find the file.

[image]

I am trying to think logically about how to get this to work but it seems the solution is far from logical. How would I make this possible?

EDIT:

The top level CMakeLists.txt only defines subfolders:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(amber VERSION 0.1.0)

add_subdirectory(amber.common)
add_subdirectory(amber.engine)
```

Comment: Not enough information. How common and engine are related in the top level CMakeLists file?

Comment: Where is `amber_object.h`? You'll need to link to `amber.common` and probably add a `PUBLIC` `target_include_directories` to `amber.common`

Comment: @ixSci: I added the information kept in the top level CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: @AlanBirtles: sorry for not showing that, but it is located in amber.common/core/

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches which might be used to do what you want. One of them works well when your project is logically structured in different libraries but you actually not going to use the libraries outside the project as standalone artifacts. In that case you can add the following in your top CMake file: `include_directories(.)` and then include it in your engine like this:

```
#include "amber.common/core/amber_object.h"
```

It is verbose but it shows where that include is coming from.

Alternatively you can just do the following in you amber.common:

```
target_include_directories(amber.common PUBLIC .)
```

and then in your engine:

```
target_link_libraries(amber.engine PRIVATE amber.common)
```

You would include it like this: `#include "core/amber_object.h"`. With the second solution you can also include `core` instead of `.`, then you would include your header simply by `#include "amber_object.h"`.